# How to show two images one by one in android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i have two images namely "a" and "b" when user open activity i want to show image "a" and second time when user again open activity want to show image"b" same for 3 4 5 6. I have tried a lot and also googled but can't found any solution.

Comment: what did you try, show some code!

Comment: save the images in an array and save the displayed Image Position in shared Preference. Every time user launch the app, you can load the image from the array with position + 1 value.

Comment: pls write some sample code i am new

Comment: how many images do you have totally?

Comment: choice Image from past activity ?

Comment: you should maintain flag for next image to be shown through shared Preference with one default value , And Update shared Preference value each time when you open your Activity , So its holds flag value for which image is to be show next time.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will help you.
Create a Shared Preferences for store the value of index.Every time Activity will create index will increment and accordingly image would change.

public class ImageShow extends Activity{

```
Integer image[]={R.drawable.icon,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.icon_audio};
int index=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("imagevalue", 0);

    index=sharedpreferences.getInt("key", 0);



    ImageView imv=new ImageView(this);
    imv.setImageResource(image[index]);


    Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", ++index);
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for this first you should put your images in your Drawble or assets folder after that you can show images in imageview and save its name in sharedpreferences as string...when user again open this activity you should check the sharedpreferences to find that which images seen with user and according that data decide to show next image to user...